# configurations for the Subdomain module in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

What are the appropriate configurations for the Subdomain module in drupal 7 on Window 7 running XAMPP?

My site is localhost/example

Here are the changes I have made:

**settings.php**

```
$cookie_domain = '';
```

Leaving this commented out gives me an error

> "The $cookie_domain variable in settings.php is not set".

Uncommenting and putting in "localhost", ".localhost", "example", ".example" gives me an `"Access denied"` error.

It seems to accept "localhost/example" or a blank ' ', although I don't know if this is the right thing to do.

**host**

```
127.0.1.1   localhost  example
```

(and I can successfully ping ideastar)

**http.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example
ServerAlias *.example
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

getting the fallowing error

Subdomain error: localhost and subdomain-test.localhost did not resolve to the same IP address. Your DNS may be improperly configured and subdomains will likely not work.

Answer (score 0):

First you should create two virtual host one for main domain and another for sub-domain. For ex: like we have two domains example.com and test.example.com to setup on local host. I am assuming that you have a fresh install of Xampp on your machine. Your virtual host [\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf] file should have these entries:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "\xampp\htdocs\example"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "\xampp\htdocs\example"
    ServerName test.example.com
    ServerAlias test.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now open you system host file and make the following entries below the line "127.0.1.1   localhost" (localhost ip 127.0.0.1)

```
127.0.1.1   example.com
127.0.1.1   test.example.com
```

\xampp\htdocs\example this directory should contain your Drupal setup.

Cookie domain entry should be as per the below line

```
$cookie_domain = '.example.com';
```

i have assumed that you already have a Drupal site running at http:\localhost\example.